# Error displaying multiple photos

Tags: php, html

I am trying to save 2 photos to my MySQL database. I can only see one of the 2 photos in the database (i.e. its name) but I see the 2 photos in the folder I store my photos. ( A picture of how the database looks like is attached.) When I try to display the 2 photos, I only see that one photo that I saw in the database. What is the problem here?

Html Code to upload photo

```
<input type="file" id="_photo" name="_photo[]" multiple="multiple">
<input type="button" id="add_more" class="" value="Add More Files"/>
```

Code to save photos in database and folder

```
    if (!empty($_FILES['_photo']['name'][$i])) {
        if ($_FILES['_photo']['type'][$i] == 'image/jpeg') {
            $upload_folder = "./profile_pix/";
            $pic_name = time() . ".jpg";
            $pic_path = $upload_folder . $pic_name;
            require_once "include/resize.php";
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['_photo']['tmp_name'][$i], $pic_path)) {
                    $image = new Resize($pic_path);
                    $image->resizeImage(180, 180, 'crop');
                    $image->saveImage($pic_path);
                    //thumbnail
                    $image = new Resize($pic_path);
                    $image->resizeImage(50, 50, 'crop');
                    $image->saveImage($upload_folder . "thumb/" . $pic_name);
                }
        }
    }
    else {
    $pic_name="default_house.png";
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO offers
                (accommodation, school, date,  available, member_id, photo, )
                 VALUES
                (:accommodation, :school, :date, 'yes', :member_id, '$pic_name', )"; 

$query = $db->($sql, array(..........));
```

Code to display Uploaded Photos

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myDatabase";
foreach ($db->query($sql) AS $result){
echo "
<img src='profile_pix/{$result['photos']}' width = '30' height ='30px' style=' margin-top:8px;'/>
";
}enter image description here
```

Comment: Use foreach also for saving the image link in database

Answer (score 0):

Try following,hope it will work. Remember your column is `photo`, not `photos`.

```
<?php
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM myDatabase";
   $sqlres = mysql_query($sql);
   foreach ($sqlres AS $result){
     echo "<img src='profile_pix/".$result['photo']." width = '30' height ='30px' style=' margin-top:8px;'/>";
   }
?>
```